# Four letters are picked from the word BREAKDOWN. What is the probability that there is at least one vowel among the letters?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I know that the right answer is 0.881 but i'm not sure how to get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the easy-to-verify form:
$$
1-\frac{\binom{6}{4}\cdot\binom{3}{0}}{\binom{9}{4}}
$$

Comment: could you please explain why you have 9C4 dividing the product of 6C4 and 3C0?

Comment: There are 9 letters: 6 consonats and 3 vowels. The probablity that you are asking is equal 1 minus the probablity of four consonants. Hence you are picking up 4 consonats from 6, 0 vowels from 3, and generally 4 letters from 9.

Answer (score 2):

Use the complement rule. $P(\text{at lest one vowel}) = 1 - P(\text{no vowels})$.  You have 6 non-vowels and 3 vowels.  What can you do with this?  The easiest thing to do is to draw a probability tree.